# Libgdx wont render materials

Tags: android, eclipse, 3d, libgdx, blender

Long story short: Libgdx won't render the materials of objects that I create using blender.

I have an object called grass.obj and its material grass.mtl and the texture image its using grass.png the object looks just fine on blender but when I render it in my program it renders the shape(mesh) of the object but not the textures. So it looks like this:

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

```
this.game_assets.load(SURFACE_FILE,Model.class);
this.game_assets.load(EDGES_FILE,Model.class);

ModelInstance surfaceInstance = new ModelInstance(surface);
surfaceInstance.transform.setToTranslation(x, SURFACE_DEPTH, z);
instances.add(surfaceInstance);
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show how you're loading the model(s) and texture(s)?

Comment: I did. just edited the post. thanks!

Comment: It could be the image file is not where Libgdx expects it or has a different name. I think it expects it to be in the same directory as the g3db or g3dj file. If you use g3dj (JSON) format, you can look at the file to see if the image file name matches up with your actual image file.

Comment: I'm using obj or g3db.